# While loop using concurrent.futures ProcessPoolExecutor

Tags: python, while-loop, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, concurrent.futures

For a project, I need to do many tasks using Python. I would like to use multiple processes and let the program run for a (very) long time. I therefore wants to use a while loop with the module concurrent.futures.

I am guessing it is not a good idea, but right now I'm just using a for loop with a high number inside, which is not that good either.

Maybe I need to create a future, every time one is ended ?
I am not sure how to handle that

The very simplified version of my code looks like this:

```
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor, as_completed

def task(n):
    print(f'Task {n} started...')
    time.sleep(10)  # Reaally long task
    print(f'Task {n} ended.')
    return n

numbers = range(0, 10)
with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=2) as executor:
    futures = [executor.submit(task, number) for number in numbers]

    for future in as_completed(futures):
        print(f'future job n°{future.result()} ended')
```

Any help is welcome :)
Thanks!

EDIT:
What I ended up doing

```
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor, as_completed
import time


def task(n):
    # print(f'Task {n} started...')
    time.sleep(1)  # Reaally long task
    # print(f'Task {n} ended.')
    return n


number = 12
step_size = 3
while True:
    numbers = range(number, number + step_size)
    with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=2) as executor:
        futures = [executor.submit(task, number) for number in numbers]

        for future in as_completed(futures):
            print(f'future job n°{future.result()} ended')
    number += step_size
```